# basic python syntax

Tags: python, syntax

Today I'm dealing with python code for the first time. Basically, have no time for python tutorial. I'm Java background. If you could help me with python syntax, that would be great. Piece of code:

```
def fromData(headerdata, offset = 0):
        """Return a new Header object from the supplied binary data."""
        (id, flags, qdc, anc, nsc, arc,) = \
              struct.unpack_from(">6H", headerdata, offset)
        qr_ = (flags >> Header.OFFSET_QR) & 0x1
```

questions:

1. what is this

   ```
   (id, flags, qdc, anc, nsc, arc,) = \
         struct.unpack_from(">6H", headerdata, offset)
   ```

   mean? What is it doing?
2. why the "arc" ends with ","?
3. why qr is followed by "_"
4. what is `>6H`. could you redirect me for the list of formats?

Comment: "You've got no time". And yet you expect us to devote time? You didn't even spend the time to format the question well. We expect you to put some effort in before you ask the questions. Please read the [faq]. What you need to read up to understand the code are Python **tuples**.

Comment: yes, since I assume I'm asking people with more expertise than I am

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html ... and the trailing underscore is just part of the variable name, it isn't magic.

Comment: at least some links would be useful. I don't even know how to search for the answers for my questions

Comment: Search for 'python' and 'struct' - the link I posted is the first hit. Come on, there's rushed and then there's just lazy.

Comment: We can't magically teach you Python. Programming is hard.

Comment: @katrielalex: Well, programming in python isn't as hard :)  http://xkcd.com/353/

Comment: @Useless my reply with "links" was meant for David Heffernan.
Thanks for the link

Comment: @katrielalex not asking to teach me. I have 4 specific questions

Comment: @nzrksafina That's true. However, your questions are very basic, and indicate that you don't really know any Python (as you mention in your question). That makes them -- although not inherently bad questions -- not a good fit for StackOverflow, since to answer them properly we would first have to teach you Python.

Comment: The basic problem here is that you started your question by saying, and I paraphrase, "I'm too lazy to do a websearch, could you tell me the answer." I know that's not what you said, but it's how it came across. All you needed to do was to re-structure the question a little. You've picked up 5 down votes and had your question closed in 10 minutes. That means a lot of people share my view. You just need to take a bit more time and show us that you have made some effort yourself. Then you'll get lots of help.

Comment: @Useless true, I've been in the struct page before, for some reason didn't scroll. my bad.

Comment: no, I got the answers without anybody teaching me
1,2) look at tuples
3)is part of variable. i was confused because i thought it wasn't declared anywhere,since I didn't see type variable declaration. 
4) scroll the struct page down
Thank you everybody, although 5 downs are bit harsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C `struct` can be packed into flat binary data, which is what Python 2 calls a string. The `struct` module lets you take a string that represents one of these C structs, and "unpack" it into a Python data structure.

To do so you call [`struct.unpack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack). You need to specify a format string (as defined in the linked docs), and it returns a tuple of values unpacked from the data.